# Добавить / Убрать класс по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скажем код

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
        <ul>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

и есть js

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu span').toggle(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".menu ul").show();  
        $(this).addClass('red');
        },function(){
        $(this).siblings(".menu ul").hide();  
        $(this).removeClass('red');
    });
});
```

Он прекрасно работает с версией jquery 1.7.2, но с последней версией, не хочет. Может кто подскажет, что не так?

Comment: А поведение одинаковое во всех браузерах? Какую версию используете в которой не работает?

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в [методе toggle, который используется](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Данные метод был удален в версии 1.9

В новых версиях его можно заменить [функцией click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".menu ul").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE** открыт только один

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu span').click(function() {
    $('.active').add(
        $(this).toggleClass('red')
        .parent()
      ).toggleClass('active')
      .children('ul')
      .toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Ссылка</a><span class="pp">Клик</span>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А как сделать что бы оно было открывалось / закрывалось поочередно?

Comment: @Константин, для этого надо выбрать соседние li и закрыть в них

Comment: @Константин, либо просто присваивать активному li класс и по нему закрывать

Comment: @Константин, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

В общем вот вариант с добавлением активного класса и поочередной логике открытия

```
$('.menuSite span').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings(".menuSite ul").slideToggle();
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
   $('.menuSite span').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('active');
   $('.menuSite span').not($(this)).siblings('ul').slideUp();
});
```

Буду рад сам пользоваться, и может кому поможет в проектах